# Pass data to a container view from parent view

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am using a container view (v2-container) to display data in a view controller (v2)

But i am sending data from root view controller (v1) to that view

v1 -> v2 data passing is done by using following code

```
accountContainerViewController.viewControllerID = menuItem.tag
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(accountContainerViewController, animated: true)
```

and its working well

but for v2 -> v2-container data passing i used following code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "signInSegue"{
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as LoginViewController)

        controller.viewControllerID = viewControllerID
    }
}
```

But this happens only first time , But i need to pass the data every time that v2 appears with v2-container

can any one tell me what i did wrong

thanks in advance